# Getting this error trying to sync git changes: error: cannot spawn sh

Tags: bash, git, visual-studio-code, git-bash

> error: cannot spawn sh: Function not implemented error: cannot spawn c:\Users\jasonb\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\git\dist\askpass.sh: Function not implemented error: cannot spawn bash: Function not implemented fatal: could not read password for 'https://PRIVATE_NAME@dev.azure.com/PRIVATE_PATH': no such file or directory

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling git, and I set the correct git path in settings.json in vscode. Both git and vscode are updated.